# Do emblems give bonuses or are they just for show?

Tags: destiny

There are some emblems for sale, by Speaker and by factions. Do they have some hidden buffs? Do faction emblems give some reputation gain bonus?

Answer (score 3):

Event emblems (The Queen's Wrath and Iron Banner) give 10% reputation gain bonus for event activities.

All others do not have any bonuses, they're just for show.

Faction emblems do not increase rep gain. I did some tests and with nightfall bonus bounties still give +62 and +125 rep (50 and 100 plus 25% from nightfall) even with both faction emblem and banner equiped.

I did not find any bonuses in Speaker emblems too. There were some rumors for hidden buffs (on [Destiny forums](http://www.bungie.net/en/Forum/Post/70492651/0/0) and [Gamefaqs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/704532-destiny/70177239)), but in my tests I did not find any effects described. I did not try all of them though, only several.

Another source - [Planet Destiny](http://planetdestiny.com/secret-bonuses-emblems/):

```
We have off the record Bungie confirmation that emblems do not have 
any hidden buffs or bonuses of any kind.
```

Comment: The event emblems are an exception. Having the emblems equipped during bounty turnins during Queen's Wrath and Iron Banner *did* give bonuses.

Comment: @FAE, thanks, totally forgot about those! Added to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Only the event emblems give bonuses, all of the other emblems are just for show.

Comment: Thanks, totally forgot about those. Didn't do Iron Banner and Queen was so long ago =)

Answer (score -2):

some of the emblems from the speaker provides a little more chance of engram drops.